# VScode Port Tab disappear

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was using the 'forward port' functionality in VSCode, and I'm not sure if I did something wrong, but the PORT tab disappeared, and I have been unable to reactivate this feature

I've tried everything. I uninstalled and then reinstalled VSCode, deleted the settings.json file, removed extensions, and checked with a right-click in the terminal to see if it was hidden. I'm hoping someone can tell me if they've had the same problem or how I can resolve it.

Comment: Are you using Windows Subsystem for Linux? And are you on at least version 1.82? Have you tried Ctrl+Shift+P to restore views via `workbench.action.resetViewLocations`?